# Can one aquire regular objects through biya?

Tags: halacha, transactions, sexuality

The Mishna (Kiddushin 1:1) tell us that one can acquire a wife through money (kinyan), documents (shtar) or biya (intercourse). The first two are commonly used to buy and sell regular objects, but could one acquire objects through biya, either with the owner or with the object itself?

Comment: When you learn the drashas in Kidushin that establish each method of kinyan based on others, this question naturally comes up ... and then gets shot down by your rebbe. Or at least, I vaguely remember that happening in 9th grade.

Comment: I skipped 9th grade. Isaac Moshe rabbenu, please tell me how we know that biya doesn't acquire other articles?

Comment: Moshe Rabbeinu learned the whole Torah straight from God as if through a crystal-clear window. Me in 9th grade, not so much.

Comment: biya is applicable only to women. It cannot occur in any other case.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: Explain to me how this would work, bi'ah on objects? (Actually, don't. This is a public forum.)

Answer (score 5):

Look at [the Mishnayot](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90) a few after that one:

> נכסים שיש להם אחריות, נקנין בכסף ובשטר ובחזקה.‏
>   [Land] is acquired through money, documents and [usage].

Examples (given by Bartenura) of the "usage" technique for land include plowing the land, locking the opening, and building a fence.

Additionally, you can find that:

> עבד כנעני נקנה בכסף ובשטר ובחזקה.‏
>   A Cannanite slave is acquired through money, documents and [usage].

Examples (given by Bartenura) of the "usage" technique for such a slave include tying the master's shoes, carrying his belongings, and bathing him.

---

Of course, the only object that Biah could be done with is a human woman, and the only time one buys a woman is as a slave. Indeed the Talmud ([Kiddushin 22b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=22b&format=pdf)) wonders whether or not a maidservant can be acquired through Biah, concluding she cannot as she also benefits from the Biah so it can't be considered using her for slave labor.

Comment: Is the downvote because you don't like the answer or you don't like the question?

Comment: +1. I'm guessing that someone downvoted possibly because you didn't explicitly say that objects cannot be acquired through *bi'ah*. But they didn't comment, so who knows?